# Select elements under certain class name

Tags: jquery

I have a question regarding the selector.

I want to select the input field that is not under certain class.

My html

```
<div class='test'>
   ……
   <input type='text'></input>
 // more input field 
     <div class='nonTarget>
        <input type='text' ></input>
     <div>

</div>
```

I want to input field under test class but not nonTarget div.

I have

```
  var test = $('.test :not(.answer) input');
         test.each(function(){
             console.log($(this).val())
         })
```

but it seems select every input fields.. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Matt's comment is right _ jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtKdr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$('.test input:not(.nonTarget input)')`.

It uses the [`:not` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), and finds all `inputs` which are descendants of `.test`, but which don't match the selector `.nonTarget input` (i.e. aren't a descendant of `.nonTarget`).

See it here; http://jsfiddle.net/LAgkX/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery:

```
$('.test').children('input').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

The `.children()` selector only goes one step down the DOM tree, so you should be good.

Comment: will only work if the inputs are direct descendants of `.test`

Comment: @koala_dev The OP didn't indicate he wanted anything different.

Comment: @crush well, to be honest the question is kind of vague, what do the dots `...` above the input mean? you're assuming it means siblings, but might as well be other container elements

Comment: "I want to input field under test class but not nonTarget div." i took this as direct children of test class, hence my answer. obviously an interpretation, but i think the most likely one.